# How was Danvers able to confirm Fury was human?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

When they're at the bar, Danvers starts asking Fury questions about his past, to make sure he's a human and not a Skrull posing as a human.

Fury replies back with a series of information about his past, which include some "Earth-stuff" (names of places, etc.) — none of which she's able to fact-check.

Furthermore, she then tries to prove to him she's not a Skrull by firing her photon blast thingy, to which he replies something like "how does that prove anything to me?," which basically illustrates the point I'm trying to make:

**If they're both completely oblivious to each other's past, culture, abilities, etc., how can any information they exchange be relevant in figuring out if they're Skrulls or not?**

Comment: ..and how did he beat her to the bar in the first place?

Comment: [Same question over on Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/97771/46980), though it sounds like you're also interested in knowing how Fury knew Danvers wasn't a Skrull.

Comment: I can't remember Carol's questions to Fury, maybe she was just seeing how quickly/naturally he responded? As for the second point, I don't think Danver's response to Fury was necessarily designed to prove to him that she wasn't a Skrull, I think it was more a demonstration that she's so powerful, he should just be grateful she's working with him and not vaporising him on the spot.

Answer (score 2):

Carol's questions to Fury were probably more testing how "realistic" they sounded and his response rate and confidence. People can usually easily recall the details of the questions she asks him because they are about major events in their life. Therefore, answering them would be quick like Fury does when replying. However, a Skrull can only access recent memories and so would likely struggle on the spot in the quick fire rate the questions are coming in to come up with answers that sound believable.

> **Carol:** Skrulls can only assume recent memories of their host bodies.
>
> <sub>*Captain Marvel*</sub>

Note that there is also a scene shift afterwards with a time skip and so Carol might not have trusted him 100% in the moment but fact checked somehow later on. The fact he gave actual real place names and events would help with that.

For proving Carol is Carol she shoots the photon blast and whilst this wouldn't make Fury 100% sure she isn't a Skrull because he doesn't know them, it should help. Remember when they first meet a Skrull shoots at the pair of them but doesn't use photon blasts. If Skrulls could do that they wouldn't carry weapons, which is part of the reason Carol doesn't. Why carry bulkiness and weight when you yourself can do much better? So he should be somewhat confident she isn't a Skrull from the demonstration even if he isn't fully bought over.

On top of that it could also be noted that Fury is now in no position to fight back against her, 9 times out of 10 she is going to beat him so safer for him to play a long game if he doesn't trust her. From the same perspective Carol could have done it to intimidate Fury to try and get him to do what she wants without having to reveal any information.

It's also worth noting that this test would never be 100% accurate and is more of a quick test to see if they can trust each other. It isn't foolproof but more of a gut feeling type of test. And for what it's worth I got the impression they were both somewhat sure each other wasn't a Skrull at the start of the scene but did it as more of a formality and to get to know each other a bit. It appeared to be more of a trust test than a species test.

Comment: Wouldn't the argument that Carol isn't a Skrull because Skrulls can't produce photon blasts be an equally valid (but incorrect) argument against her being human? (Not saying that's what she was arguing, but just that it would be hypothetically just as relevant to the photon blast.)